# Action bar removal for API Level 8

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Hi how do i remove the action bar. I tried the following code:

```
ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

But it says  that it is only possible for API Level 11. I am  trying to develop for API LEVEL 8.

Comment: The ActionBar didn't exist as a concept in Android until API Level 11. So you will need to clarify what it is that you are trying to remove - is it the title bar (usually a gray strip with the application title in white)? Are you using a backwards compatibility library to enable the action bar on older API levels, such as AppCompat or ActionbarSherlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`

or via Theme:
`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`